# read_sql_query in pandas not working now

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I used this function regularly until yesterday when it started throwing 'module has no attribute read_sql_query' error.

Any way to fix it? Alternatives?

Comment: Could you please post the code that is throwing the error?

Answer (score 1):

Check you connection. What database are you using? Does it need username, password?

did you create connection to database?

for an example, with simple sqlite3 library:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

a = sqlite3.connect('testing.db3')
b = pd.read_sql_query('select * from my_table', a)

print(b)
```

there is alternative: `pd.read_sql`

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

a = sqlite3.connect('testing.db3')
b = pd.read_sql('select * from my_table', a)

print(b)
```